# Fock Space Proof of $(g(x)\phi^4)_2$ Mass Gap?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, quantum-field-theory

Is there a proof that does not depend on Euclidean methods? Is this a proof? :

$V(g)$ [can be written](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103859068) as $P+R$ where $P$ is non-negative and $R$ is $N$-bounded (and hence $(H_0+\lambda P)$-bounded). $H_0+\lambda P$ is essentially self-adjoint by [this method](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103857260). (These are short proofs depending on estimates on the kernels and $\phi < \sqrt N$).

By [this theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245093/h-self-adjoint-with-mass-gap-p%E2%89%A50-%CE%A9%E2%88%88dp-h%CE%BBp-self-adjoint-%E2%9F%B9-for-%CE%BB-small), $H_0+\lambda P$ has a gap for small $\lambda$. A gap is stable under the relatively bounded perturbation $\lambda R$, so $H_0+\lambda V$ has a gap for small $\lambda$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling has pointed out that the theorem is immediate from the min-max principle.